# Android - Aplicação reiniciando após minimização

Tags: android, webview

Possuo uma aplicação android, onde apenas tenho uma tela que fica um WebView. Porém, quando o usuário acessa uma página do site, por exemplo: meusite.com.br/contact e minimiza o app. Quando ele reabre o app, ao invés dele voltar na página em que ficou, ele volta na página inicial(em meusite.com.br). 
Já adicionei eventos para atualizar a variável que modifica a url, para modificá-la quando a url for modificada. Também adicionei eventos para salvar o estado da aplicação e ainda sim continua o mesmo erro.

Comment: Ola User e bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Forneça mais detalhes do seu problema, inclusive parte dos fontes atuais e exemplos do que você já tentou. Aproveite e faça o [tour] e visite a [help] principalmente no tópico [ask]

Comment: Coloque todo o código referente ao WebView...

Comment: Poste o código.

Answer (score 2):

Para impedir que o aplicativo "reinicie" após minimizar, você deve salvar a [instância](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)

Para isto você deve usar os metodos `onSaveInstanceState`, `onRestoreInstanceState` e `super.onCreate` no seu `Activity`.

Ficaria algo como (leia os comentários no código):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView meuWebView;//Seu webView

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);//"super" envia o comando para classe "parent"
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);//Salva Activity 
        meuWebView.saveState(outState);//Salva WebView
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);//Restaura o Activity 
        meuWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);//Restaura o WebView
    }
}
```